# Proper foreach loop procedure with resizing image(s)

Tags: php, image, imagecreatefrompng

Only one of the thumbnail images saves to the folder of this script even though several images are uploading. I'm thinking it must be something related to the iteration of the foreach loop.  This is only the resizing script posted below. Does anyone have a quick fix? Thanks

```
define('THUMBS_DIR', 'C: /inetpub / wwwroot / mysite / images / thumbs / ');
define('MAX_WIDTH', 90);
define('MAX_HEIGHT', 100);
if (array_key_exists('upload', $_POST)) 
{
    $original = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    foreach ($original as $number => $tmp_file) 
    {
        $original = ($tmp_file);  
    }

    if (!$original) 
    {
        echo 'NoImageSelected'; 
    }
}  else { 
    list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($original);

    if ($width <= MAX_WIDTH && $height <= MAX_HEIGHT) 
    {
        $ratio = 1; 
    }   elseif ($width > $height) {
        $ratio = MAX_WIDTH/$width;
    } else { 
        $ratio = MAX_HEIGHT/$height; 
    }

    $imagetypes = array(' / . gif$ / ',' / . jpg$ / ',' / . jpeg$ / ',' / . png$ / ');
    $name = preg_replace($imagetypes, '', basename($file[$location]));     
    $moved = @ move_uploaded_file($original[$location], THUMBS_DIR.$file); 

    if ($moved) 
    {
        $result[] = $_FILES['image']['name'].'succesfullyuploaded';
        $original = $ext.$file[$location]; 
    }else{
        $result = 'Problemuploading'.$_FILES['image']['name'];
    }

    if ($type == 1) 
    {
        $source = imagecreatefromgif($original);
    } elseif ($type == 2) {
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($original); 
    } elseif ($type == 3) {
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($original);
    } else { 
        $result = 'Cannotidentifythefiletype';
    }
}
```

Comment: figureditout...needs                                                    $i=0; foreach ($tmp_file as $original){      //code  block ...else{ $result = 'Cannot identify file type'; }   $i++; //with variables notated as $original[$i]

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more descriptive about what you want the script to do. I think your problem could be in :

```
$original = ($tmp_file);
```

You are overwriting the variable that you use in your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The purpose is to resize any images that are uploaded from my input type="file" input type="upload" form. The form(not shown above) works great for single and multiple image uploads.  But only one of the resized images is being created and saved to the 'thumbails' folder.

Comment: figured it out... needs $i=0; foreach ($tmp_file as $original){